# Populate all months between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have been trying to make a formula in Excel that populates the month between two dates.

All i get is DatedIF() but it does not fulfil the requirments.

Here is the picture that i want from the Excel Formula. If i update any date in the start date or end date formula will automatically calculate the all months between the dates and give the result as available in attached picture.

[image]

Code result and the result i want. Code should work accordingly with the dates.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AbLs8soPOgQvorwIzWLIJIooIQiVg9fvKaBdxY0tmgU/edit#gid=1340167497

```
=IF(ROW()=15,0,IFERROR(INDEX(MONTH(EDATE(Sheet1!B$4,ROW(A$15:INDEX(A:A,DATEDIF(Sheet1!B$4,Sheet1!G$1,"m"))))),COUNT(A$15:A15)),""))
```

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook Excel 2016, But i can drag the formula if array function is not available in excel 2016. I will drag the formula accordingly.

Comment: Not sure if '16 has the `SEQUENCE` function?  If it does you can use `=SEQUENCE(B3-B2,,0,1)` where B3 and B2 are your dates.

Comment: No its not working can we use VBA for this? If formula does not work.

Comment: Just noticed that SEQUENCE formula would have given you days of the year rather than months.... doesn't work for you either way at any rate.  Yes, a VBA solution is very possible.

Comment: Yes i can use VBA if it works

Comment: Is the zero just a zero or is there more to it? If it represents the month `12/2019`, wouldn't it be more appropriate to be `12`? Or are you not including `12/2019` in the result?

Comment: Ok we can use it 12/2019 12.

Answer (score 1):

This will populate from row five onwards.  No doubt the code could be adapted to work as an array formula.

```
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        PopulateMonths .Range("B2"), .Range("B3")
    End With

End Sub

Sub PopulateMonths(FirstDate As Range, SecondDate As Range)

    Dim MonthCount As Long
    MonthCount = DateDiff("m", FirstDate, SecondDate)
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        'This will clear from row 5, column 1 to the last piece of data in column 1.
        'If column 1 is already empty it will clear from A1:A5, so best to check if
        'there's any data to clear before this line runs (just see if A5<>"")
        .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).ClearContents
    
        Dim x As Long
        For x = 0 To MonthCount
            .Cells(x + 5, 1) = x 'Start on row 5, column 1.
        Next x
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help please have a look i updated the result of your code

Comment: I have been using this code it is working fine when i edited the end date for next months or year it gives accurate result but when i edited date for back it does not remove the given result. @Darren Bartrup-Cook

Comment: Have updated the code to clear column A before adding new data.

Comment: Thank you @Darren Bartrup-Cook now it is working great

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `A4`:

```
=IF(ROW()=4,0,IFERROR(INDEX(MONTH(EDATE(B$1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,DATEDIF(B$1,B$2,"m"))))),COUNT(A$3:A3)),""))
```

Drag down.

Note: With, for example, end-date being "30-12-2021" this will only work up to 11. If you would still want to see up to 12, you'd need to use `EOMONTH()` as a nested function in there.

Comment: thank you for solving the problem i have attached a sheet link where i replace the cell reference tosheet1 but its not working can you please check it.

Comment: @Learning, I don't see your formula...?

Comment: In Sheet2 cell C15

Comment: Mistakenly added Sheet link in @Darren Bartrup-Cook answer. JvdV

Comment: Yes Excel 2016 I just added as an example

Comment: @Learning, are you sure you entered the formula through CSE?

Comment: let me share an picture with you.

Comment: @Learning, that would have been `=IFERROR(SMALL(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,DATEDIF(B$1,B$2,"M")+1))-1,ROW(1:1)),"")`

Comment: thank you so much @JvdV the formula you created for newly post has an error please check it as well

Answer (score 0):

### Populate Months Between Two Dates

- The following is an automated version which uses the `Worksheet Change event` i.e. it runs only if you manually or via `VBA` change the values (not by formula). You don't have to run anything just copy the codes to the appropriate modules and adjust the values in the constants section.
- If for some reason you don't want the automation, you can delete the code in the sheet module, delete the three constants below `Option Explicit` in the standard module and uncomment the three constants in `populateMonths`. Now it will only work with `populateMonthsInit`.
- If the start date is the last date of the month, the month will not be included. Similarly, if the end date is the first date of the month, the month will not be included. This can easily be adjusted.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Union(Range(StartDateCell), Range(EndDateCell)), Target)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        populateMonths
    End If
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit
 
Public Const StartDateCell As String = "B1"
Public Const EndDateCell As String = "B2"
Private Const FirstCell As String = "B4"

Sub populateMonthsInit()
    populateMonths
End Sub

Sub populateMonths(Optional ws As Worksheet)
    'Const StartDateCell As String = "B1"
    'Const EndDateCell As String = "B2"
    'Const FirstCell As String = "B4"
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    End If
    With ws.Range(FirstCell)
        Dim Data As Variant
        Data = getMonthNumbers(.Worksheet.Range(StartDateCell).Value, _
            .Worksheet.Range(EndDateCell).Value)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Value = 0 ' Not sure what that's all about.
        If Not IsEmpty(Data) then
            .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
        End if
    End With
End Sub

Function getMonthNumbers( _
    ByVal StartDate As Date, _
    ByVal EndDate As Date) _
As Variant
    On Error GoTo clearError
    Dim Months As Long: Months = DateDiff("m", StartDate, EndDate)
    Dim StartMonth As Long
    If Month(StartDate + 1) = Month(StartDate) Then
        Months = Months + 1
        StartMonth = modMonth(Month(StartDate))
    Else
        StartMonth = modMonth(Month(StartDate) + 1)
    End If
    If Month(EndDate - 1) <> Month(EndDate) Then
        Months = Months - 1
    End If
    Dim Data() As Long: ReDim Data(1 To Months, 1 To 1)
    Data(1, 1) = StartMonth
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Months
        Data(i, 1) = modMonth(Data(i - 1, 1) + 1)
    Next i
    getMonthNumbers = Data
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function modMonth( _
    m As Long) _
As Long
    modMonth = IIf(m Mod 12, m Mod 12, 12)
End Function

Sub TESTgetMonthNumbers()
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = getMonthNumbers(Range("B1"), Range("B2"))
    If Not IsEmpty(Data) Then
        Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(Data), vbLf)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Nope."
    End If
End Sub
```